# Estimating Azure Search Cost

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-search

I'm fairly new to Azure platform and need some help with cost estimates for Azure Search service.
Every month we will have about 500GB worth of files that will dropped into Azure Blob Storage. We would like to index these files using Azure Search just based on the file names. 
When I look at the Standard S2 pricing, it has the following text for storage:
*100 GB/partition (max 1.2 TB documents per service)*. What does this mean? Does it mean that once my storage crosses 1.2TB, I'll need to purchase another Service? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If a tier's capacity turns out to be too low based on your needs, you will need to provision a new service at the higher tier and then reload your indexes. Kindly note that there is no in-place upgrade of the same service from one SKU to another.

Storage is constrained by disk space or by a hard limit on the maximum number of indexes, document, or other high-level resources, whichever comes first.

A service is provisioned at a specific tier. Jumping tiers to gain capacity involves provisioning a new service (there is no in-place upgrade). For more information, see [Choose a SKU or tier](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-sku-tier). To learn more about adjusting capacity within a service you've already provisioned, see [Scale resource levels for query and indexing workloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-capacity-planning).
Check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity#subscription-limits) for more details on this topic.

S2 offers the following (at this time) - Storage per partition = 100 GB, with Partitions per service = 12 and, the Partition size = 100 GB.

You could use Pricing Calculator (https://azure.microsoft.com/pricing/calculator/) for the cost estimation as well.

Answer (score 0):

The [storage limits for Azure Search](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/search/) refers to the size of documents in the index, which can be bigger or smaller than your original blobs depending on your use case.

For example, if you want to do text searches on blob content then the index size will be bigger than your original blobs. Whereas if you only want to search for file names, then size of the original blobs becomes irrelevant and only the number of blobs will affect your Azure Search index size.